# Replace the title of an HTML image

Tags: php, regex, image, title

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the title portion of an image (`title="Title is here"`) in PHP, but I cannont get it to work, so could someone please help?

The title could be literally anything, so I need to find `title"{anything here}"` and replace that (as below).

I'm trying to us `preg_replace()`, but if there is a better way, I'm open to suggestions.

I've tried several different variations, but I think this is not too far off the mark -

```
$pattern = '#^title="([a-zA-Z0-9])"$#';
$replacement = 'title="Visit the '.$service['title'].' page';
$service_image = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $service_image);
```

Comment: How about using Jquery for that?

Comment: You're missing a double quote : `'title="Visit the '.$service['title'].' page"'`, and your pattern doesn't accept spaces or dashes

Comment: @freebird: How about not? OP wants this on the server side, jQuery is not a magic solution.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: @freebird - No jQuery thanks, I'm looking to do this server side.

Comment: @samsamX - Thanks for the heads up, I was missing a quote, but I've gone in another direction with DOMDocument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = '<img src="whatever.jpg" title="Anything">';


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(0);
/** @var $img DOMElement  Now, $img contains the DOM note representing the image. */
$img->setAttribute("title", "Whatever you want here!");

/* Export the image alone (if not used like this,
 * you'd get a complete HTML document including head and body).
 *
 * This ensures you only get the image.
 */
echo $dom->saveXML($img);
```

No regex for HTML please. This will work for you.

Comment: Thaks for the heads up, and it does seem better than the RegEx. I'm getting an error though - `Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in ...`. Is there a file I have to include, or is this to do with my PHP setup?

Comment: @DavidGard: What version of PHP are you running? DOM is enabled by default.

Comment: @Truth - I've managed to make DOMDocument available by installing `php53-xml`, and you code works perfectly. Thanks for the help (and the education in not parsing HTML with RegEx!!). Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Use this snippet :

```
$tag = '<img title="My Old Title" src="localhost"  alt="this is the alt"/>';
echo preg_replace('/(title)=("[^"]*")/i','title="My New Title"',$tag);
// <img title="My New Title" src="localhost" alt="this is the alt">
```

Comment: I can break that pattern in 2.8 seconds. (for instance, use `'` instead of `"`). Please don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: I've just told you, while it works, it's not **useful** as it's easily broken.